# Java Ant Job how to ship Log4j jar with my jar

Tags: java, jar, ant, log4j

Just trying to upgrade some old stuff and part of that I need to bundle my custom jar which uses Log4j. I did add the following for my `<javac>` task which compiles successfully.

```
<path id="my.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${mainpath}">
        <include name="**/*log4j*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

    <javac srcdir="src/java" destdir="build/filez/java" debug="on" deprecation="no"
           includes="my/instruments/**/*, org/apache/log4j/**/*">
        <classpath refid="my.classpath"/>
    </javac>
```

However, In my `<jar>` job I cannot see any `log4j` dependency packed with my custom jar. This might be a silly question, but how do ensure that my custom-jar does not fail when called from another application since the dependency isn't packed? Will it be okay as long as log4j has been loaded by classloader in the target application?

Additionally, do I need to add something in my Manifest for this?

**I cannot use Maven (yes I know) for a little while, so cannot solve this problem with maven**

Comment: If you want to include a file in your jar, that is controlled by the `jar` task, not  `javac`. Whether or not you need to include log4j in your jar depends on whether it is a runtime or compile time dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [One-JAR](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) to package your code along with it's dependencies into one big executable JAR.

It can be used either as a standalone tool from the command line or as a task defined in build.xml.

```
<!-- Construct the One-JAR file -->   
<one-jar destfile="hello.jar" manifest="hello.mf">
    <main>
        <!-- Construct main.jar from classes and source code -->
        <fileset dir="${classes.dir}/src"/>
    </main>
    <lib>
        <fileset file="${build.dir}/lib.jar" />
    </lib>
</one-jar>
```

Comment: education, education, education - I can only remember these words!! A question please! Do I need to add anything to the manifest? I am adding a manifest called `my-MANIFEST.MF" to this one-jar.

Comment: Nothing apart from the main-class I think

Comment: Hang on! this is not part of Ant - this is something custom?

Comment: It's an external Ant task, it's fairly common to use those for functionality not built into Ant itself